# How to effectly see code changes in git when used to cvs

Tags: git

We have recently changed from cvs to git. I am the person responsible for publishing new versions of our applications (and also doing most of the code). Since I do most of the coding, I work directly on the master branch. Occationally some other coworker does some small stuff. 
When working with cvs, I would allways be notified when commiting that something had been done with the file, and could see very clearly what the others had done. To try to get the same control on git, I have instructed them to do the following when they are doing changes:

```
1. Make a new branch. 
2. Do your changes. 
3. Tell me that you are finished, so that I may commit and push my stuff to master.
4. Merge your branch into master.
```

I may then see the diffs etc by doing git fetch origin, git diff master origin/master and git merge origin/master
I don't know if this is the best approach? (Do you have other suggestions?) But it seems to work to some degree. The main problem is what sometimes happens. One of them leaves a message: "I just fixed a couple of some very small things and pushed it to the master branch". 
When this happens, I often have lots of uncommited changes. I then commit these, and then the "fun" begins. I want to be able to see through and validate their code, but after "git fetch origin", "git diff master origin/master" will not only show their changes but all of mine. It is very difficult to see exactly what they have done to my beloved master branch. After git merge origin/master I at least know what files are affected, but have to uninuitively compare the files with MY commit and not THEIR commit (I use eclipse, compare with history), to see the changes. Is this the best way to see other peoples changes? Or is there a better way? I have worked with git a couple of months now, and when it comes to being in control of the code I find it is not as easy as csv, but perhaps since it is a distributed revision system I just cannot get the same amount of control?

EDIT: Changed the title of the question to more reflect what I am asking: How do I easily see what code changes other people have done in git?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using a GUI for Git instead of trying to do it on the command line. At least for me, it is easier to visualize the history in a GUI.

I like to use Atlassian's SourceTree: https://www.atlassian.com/software/sourcetree/overview

From there you can see commits that are out on the remote and see what was changed, without having to pull the changes into your own local repo.

Example screenshot of Telerik's Kendo UI repo in SourceTree:

[image]

---

If you really want to be concerned with what people push to `master`, you could always set up your Git server to not allow users to commit directly to master, and instead have them create branches, then you do the merges from branch to master. I've never set that up myself, but there is some info on it here: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-An-Example-Git-Enforced-Policy

Comment: Thank you, I'm looking into SourceTree now, it looks promising.